# State Processor API and Flink SQL jobs

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I have a job using a simple SQL query:

```
select file_name, count(*) from source group by file
```

Now using State Processor API to read the checkpoint saved by the job I have to choose proper state object: list, keyed etc.

Now how I'm supposed to know which object was chosen for state management by Table/SQL API?
Can this information be somehow inferred?

Comment: I'm wondering if you could use `EXPLAIN PLAN` to understand the generated optimized plan. See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/sql/explain/

Comment: It contains some information helpful in troubleshooting performance issues, however it doesn't contain information about state object being used - when debugging I can see it's OperatorState but I don't know what primitive it uses (List, Union list state, broadcast state). I believe this information could be useful for some performance concerns as well. Do you think it would be possible to add this functionality? Or maybe I'm totally wrong and trying to achieve something unavailable?

Comment: The SQL statements gets optimized and transformed, before the code for running the actual job is generated. I don't think this is something that's envisioned to be possible with Flink. SQL is for declarative uses cases, to abstract exactly everything that you're now trying to figure out

Comment: OK, understood. Is there a way to see this generated code?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of